# I have 10 files in Unix folder with .txt extension, here I need to get all files apart from fgh.txt (any one) file, what is the UNIX Command?

Tags: shell, command-line, grep, find

I have 10 files in Unix folder with .txt extension. Here I need to get all files apart from fgh.txt (any one) file. What is the UNIX Command?

```
1.abc.txt
2.bcd.txt
3.cde.txt
4.def.txt
5.efg.txt
6.fgh.txt
7.ghi.txt
8.hij.txt
9.ijk.txt
10.jkl.txt
```

Here I need to get all files apart from the file `6.fgh.txt`. What is the UNIX Command?

Comment: What do you mean by "get"?

Comment: Could you correlate the leading text ("apart from fgh.txt") with the trailing text ("apart from the file 6.fgh.txt")? Do you have a partial filename match in mind, or a specific file?

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please indicate so with the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

With ***find*** command:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" ! -name "fgh.txt"
```

- `-name "*.txt"` - to find files with names corresponding the pattern (all txt file)
- `! -name "fgh.txt"` - except the exact filename `fgh.txt`

---

If your files are really prefixed with numbers (I'm not sure about that question's edit) change the negation condition to `! -name "*fgh.txt"`

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that this will recurse into subdirectories by default, so it may return more than is needed.

Answer (score 3):

The [extglob](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching) option of the bash does the trick:

> Extended globbing as described by the bash man page:
>
> `?(pattern-list)`   Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
> `*(pattern-list)`   Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
> `+(pattern-list)`   Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
> `@(pattern-list)`   Matches one of the given patterns
> `!(pattern-list)`   Matches anything except one of the given patterns

The commands you need (to exclude any `*fgh.txt` file):

```
shopt -s extglob
ls -d -- !(*fgh).txt
```

If you want to exclude a specific file based on its full filename:

```
ls -d -- !(6.fgh.txt)
```

Comment: `!(6.fgh.txt)` would include non-txt  files. `!(6.fgh).txt` for all txt files except `6.fgh.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

Simple and elegant (assuming GNU `ls`):

```
ls -I fgh.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want that list of files in an array, in `zsh`, you have a few options:

```
setopt extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc

# using the negation glob operator:
files=((^*fgh).txt)

# using the "except" glob operator:
files=(*.txt~*fgh*)

# trimming entries from the array afterwards:
files=(*.txt)
files=(${files:#*fgh*})
```

Then use your array as you please like:

```
ls -ld -- $files
```